# Могу ли я передавать ViewModel в конструктор фрагмента

Tags: android, ооп, android-fragment, mvvm, архитектура

В моем приложении должно быть 3 фрагмента идентичных. Различие лишь в том какие данные они должны отображать. View идентичное и даже ViewModel. По хорошему мне бы передавать модель в фрагмент, но это уже будет нарушением mvvm, так как View(Fragment) будет знать о модели.

Вопрос в чем. Могу ли я передавать VM в конструктор Фрагмента и стоит ли вообще так делать, мб есть способы по-лучше, чтобы не писать повторяющийся код в фрагментах(логику отображения и логика vm),